# Command line input after reading from a file

Tags: file-io, lua, user-input

Hello I am trying to read in a file with a list of words and then have the user enter a number on the command line to choose his word. However when I run my code it does not allow me to enter a number. Here is my code:

```
function readFile(file)

     array = {}
     io.input(file)
     line = io.read()
     table.insert(array, line)

     while true do
           line = io.read()
           if line == nil then break end
           table.insert(array, line)
     end

     length = #array
     count = 1

     while count <= length do
           print(count .. ". " .. array[count])
           count = count + 1
     end

     return array

end

function chooseWord(wordArr)

     local answer
     io.write("Select a Number to choose a word")
     answer = io.read()
     local word = wordArr[answer]
     print(word)

     return word
end


words = readFile("dictionary.txt")
word = chooseWord(words)
```

If I remove the readFile function I can input perfectly fine, but once I read the file I am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use:

```
local f = io.open(file, "r")
line = f:read()
f:close()
```

etc.

In your case, you change the standard input file (with io.input) from stdin to your file and you would have to reset that afterwards. But that's imho not a good solution